# Cannot access custom column values in To-do tasks via MS Graph API using Python

Tags: python, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, task, microsoft-todo

I have created custom columns "VESSEL NAME", "VOYAGE NUMBER", "ETD" and "CUT-OFF" in my Outlook To-do task as shown on the pic below.

[Outlook tasks snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unzx6.jpg)

I need to access values in those columns via MS Graph API, but have had no luck so far.

Not sure if I am moving in the right direction, but I have added an openTypeExtension named "ZZZ" to my task as a test. I can retrieve it via the 'GET' method, but cannot locate it anywhere in Outlook hoping to find it amongst custom columns or other task fields.

Here is the Python code:

```
# In[1]:

import json
import requests

# In[2]:

token = json.load(open('ms_graph_state.jsonc'))["access_token"]
header = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+token}
header1 = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+token,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
base_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/'

# In[3]:

task_list_id = requests.get(base_url+'todo/lists/',headers=header).json()['value'][1]['id']
task_list = base_url+'todo/lists/'+task_list_id
task_id = requests.get(task_list+'/tasks/',headers=header).json()['value'][0]['id']

# In[4]:

payload = {"@odata.type" : "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension","extensionName" : "ZZZ","xxx" : "yyy"}

# In[5]:

create_oe = requests.post(task_list+'/tasks/'+task_id+'/extensions',headers=header1,json=payload).json()

# In[6]:

oe = requests.get(task_list+'/tasks/'+task_id+'/extensions/ZZZ',headers=header1).json()
oe

'''
Output:

{'@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('to-do-app%40outlook.co.nz')/todo/lists('AQMkADAwATZiZmYAZC0xNDM3LTZlYmMtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADtVcV-o2b90KtdxZu_nQLmgEA2HIj8QQFbES8Q4ESBpmcmgAAAgESAAAA')/tasks('AQMkADAwATZiZmYAZC0xNDM3LTZlYmMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADtVcV-o2b90KtdxZu_nQLmgcA2HIj8QQFbES8Q4ESBpmcmgAAAgESAAAA2HIj8QQFbES8Q4ESBpmcmgAAAUeYHQAAAA%3D%3D')/extensions/$entity",
 'extensionName': 'ZZZ',
 'id': 'microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension.ZZZ',
 'xxx': 'yyy'}

'''

# In[7]:

task = requests.get(task_list+'/tasks/'+task_id,headers=header).json()
task

'''
Output:

{'@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('to-do-app%40outlook.co.nz')/todo/lists('AQMkADAwATZiZmYAZC0xNDM3LTZlYmMtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADtVcV-o2b90KtdxZu_nQLmgEA2HIj8QQFbES8Q4ESBpmcmgAAAgESAAAA')/tasks/$entity",
 '@odata.etag': 'W/"2HIj8QQFbES8Q4ESBpmcmgAAAa4dUQ=="',
 'importance': 'normal',
 'isReminderOn': False,
 'status': 'notStarted',
 'title': 'test-to-do-task',
 'createdDateTime': '2021-08-14T20:14:22.5557165Z',
 'lastModifiedDateTime': '2021-08-17T06:46:46.260686Z',
 'id': 'AQMkADAwATZiZmYAZC0xNDM3LTZlYmMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADtVcV-o2b90KtdxZu_nQLmgcA2HIj8QQFbES8Q4ESBpmcmgAAAgESAAAA2HIj8QQFbES8Q4ESBpmcmgAAAUeYHQAAAA==',
 'body': {'content': '\r\n\r\n', 'contentType': 'text'}}

'''
```

Appreciate you help on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is currently not supported. Being said that, consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific scenario so it could be considered for future implementation.